# Coloring and Labeling points in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-text

I am trying to create a polar chart with two levels as similar to: [image]

However I am having a bit of difficulty with coloring the points, then coloring the labels without losing the color on the original points. I do not know if I should ask my questions in multiple questions or all together. I figured all together since they relate to the same graph, but if that is not allowed, please let me know and I can edit before it gets down voted. That is simply unfair. I have posted a reproducable example down below with comments to make it easier.

I have two dataframes whioh basically are the same. One of them has an extra column, `df2$plotter` that I use to create a subset of the data to then plot the second level. The color vector, `cdf,` is a vector of where I have HEX values as colors.

> 1. Coloring Points

If it was one level I would use the `scale_color_manual` and `fill/color` the points that way. However, since I have two dataframes I thought I could call a `color vector` so to say that would be used to color based on the values within the vector. Yet it does not use those colors I assigned. Instead it labels, points `D to O` as a `murky green` and not `grey`as indicated by the HEX code: `#A9A9A9` and uses the color as part of the legend. I would prefer a mapping as below. I do not know how to create a color vector such that is the values for each cell is used as the actual color, this vector also needs to work to color the labels. Secondly when I try to pass the same vector for the second level, the `aesthetics` in `geom_point` as `Error: Aesthetics must be either lenght 1 or the same as the data` This is both with adding `plotter` to the color paletter, but most likely I am guessing is do to the size of the vector itself. I would also prefer not to create another color vector, but simply refer to the first one.

•   `Alice` (both `Alice and Alice2`) is `#b79f00`

•   `Bob` is `#00ba38`

•   `Charlie` is `#00bfc4`

•   `Peter is`#619cff`

•   `Quin` is `#F8766D`

•   `Roger is`#f564e3`

•   Then `D to O` is `#A9A9A9`

> 2. Labeling and Coloring said labels

I can add labels with `geom_text.` Then I call the same data and aesthetics. My issue is partially the coloring as mentioned above, but now when I color them, I lose my `color` but keep the `fill` of my points. Observe below. I do not know why my `color` gets lost down the way or how to fix them. I tried to plot the text first then the points, but that didn't change anything nor would I have guessed it to. Each label should be the same color as its point in short.

[image]

> Reproducible Data:

```
k<-18  
ct<-12 
x_vector<-seq(1,k,1)
radius<-rep(5,k,1)
name<-c('Alice','Bob','Charlie','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','Peter','Quin','Roger')
df<-data.frame(x_vector,radius,name)

name2<-c('Alice2','Bob2','Charlie2','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','Peter2','Quin2','Roger2')
plotter<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
radius2<-rep(7,k,1)
df2<-data.frame(x_vector,radius2,name2,plotter)

color1<-c('#F8766D'
          ,'#F564E3'
          ,'#B79F00'
          )
other_color<-c(rep('#A9A9A9',ct))
color2<-c('#00BFC4'
          ,'#619CFF'
          ,'#00BA38'
          )
cdf<-c(color1,other_color,color2)  #color palette
df$label_radius<-df$radius+0.5  ##used to adjust the labels by a radius of 0.5
p<-ggplot()+
  ## Level1
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x_vector,y=radius,color=cdf,fill=cdf),size=3,shape=21)+
  geom_text(data=df,aes(x=x_vector,y=label_radius,label=name,color=name))+

  ## Level2
  geom_point(data=df2[(df2$plotter>0),], aes(x=x_vector,y=radius2,color=name2,fill=name2),size=3,shape=21)+
  geom_text(data=df2[(df2$plotter>0),], aes(x=x_vector,y=radius2,label=name2,color=name2))+

  ## transform into polar coordinates
  coord_polar(theta='x',start=0,direction=-1,clip='on')+

  ## sets up the scale to display from 0 to 7
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,7))+

  ## Used to 'push' the points so all 'k' show up.
  expand_limits(x=0)
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I'd personally prefer to have all data in one dataframe, and add another variable to it: So instead of `Bob1` and `Bob2` as `df$name`, having `df$name=Bob` and creating, say, `df$nr`. 
It is then easier to assign the same color to all `Bob` occurrences.

But sticking to your example: You can set colors values manually with `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` (see [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually)).

```
    library(ggplot2)
    k<-18  
    ct<-12 
    x_vector<-seq(1,k,1)
    radius<-rep(5,k,1)
    name<-c('Alice','Bob','Charlie','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','Peter','Quin','Roger')
    df<-data.frame(x_vector,radius,name)

    name2<-c('Alice2','Bob2','Charlie','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','Peter2','Quin2','Roger2')
    plotter<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
    radius2<-rep(7,k,1)
    df2<-data.frame(x_vector,radius2,name2,plotter)

    color1<-c(rep('#F8766D',2), # Alice and Alice2
              rep('#F564E3',2), # Bob and Bob2
              rep('#B79F00',1)  # Charlie
    )
    other_color<-c(rep('#A9A9A9',12))
    color2<-c(rep('#00BFC4',2),
              rep('#619CFF',2),
              rep('#00BA38',2)
    )
    cdf<-c(color1,other_color,color2) #color palette
    df$label_radius<-df$radius+0.5  ##used to adjust the labels by a radius of 0.5
    p<-ggplot()+
      ## Level1
      geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x_vector,y=radius,color=name,fill=name),size=3,shape=21)+
      scale_color_manual(values=cdf)+
      scale_fill_manual(values=cdf)+
      geom_text(data=df,aes(x=x_vector,y=label_radius,label=name,color=name))+

      ## Level2
      geom_point(data=df2[(df2$plotter>0),], aes(x=x_vector,y=radius2,color=name2,fill=name2),size=3,shape=21)+
      geom_text(data=df2[(df2$plotter>0),], aes(x=x_vector,y=radius2,label=name2,color=name2))+

      ## transform into polar coordinates
       coord_polar(theta='x',start=0,direction=-1)+ #,clip='on')+ # <-- the clip property does not work for me, probably due to my ggplot version 

      ## sets up the scale to display from 0 to 7
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,7))+

      ## Used to 'push' the points so all 'k' show up.
      expand_limits(x=0)
    p
```

[image]

Comment: I will look into making it a single dataframe. However, can you explain why you had to repeat the colors some 2 times and some 1. I think I would understand more if they were all repeted twice except for the grey color. Is that process used to act for the second level?

Comment: So it was just as easy as setting the colors before moving on.

Comment: ggplot assigns the colors from cdf to `df$name` alphabetically sorted. The `rep(...,1)` is for the single occurrence of `Charlie`, the `rep(...,2)` for `Alice` and `Alice2`

Comment: Instead of the data being alphabetical, I have ordered data that is alphabetically ordered. Also `charlie` should have a second level. My apologies. I probably should have specified that better. Would that simply mean changing the order of the color to reflect the order of the dataframe?

Comment: ggplot (in this version) seems to order all levels of all variables  (here: `names` and `names2`) of one aes (here: color`) alphabetically. 
So, yes, with the actual approach, if you add new names, you have to change your `cdf` variable to reflect that.
If you my answer answers your question, please mark it as the accepted one. Otherwise, you can also edit your question.

Comment: Yes it did answer my question at the time. In face making it one dataframe was more effective. Then I made my color vector. Argo I was able to adjust the code to fit my problem with ordering the names.